# sourcing the .vimrc gives E174 error

Tags: vim, vimrc

I am using vim on a Mac os X. After editing my `.vimrc` file and I want to try to reload it without restarting vim. But it gives me the following error.

```
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can reload my `.vimrc` without restarting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by a missing `!` after a `:command`:

**BAD**

```
command Foo echo "foo"
```

**GOOD**

```
command! Foo echo "foo"
```

See `:help e174`.

---

You reload your `~/.vimrc` with this command:

```
:so $MYVIMRC
```

---

The answers to both questions can be found in Vim's documentation.

Comment: Did you even READ the answer? Nowhere does it suggest adding `!` after the `:so` command!

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because the key you are trying to map is already mapped to something else. Adding a `!` overwrites your previous binding.

So if the line. that causes the error is:

```
:map <F6> :so $HOME/.vimrc<CR>
```

substitute it with:

```
:map! <F6> :so $HOME/.vimrc<CR>
```